# Understanding memory fragmentation due to char arrays in functions

Tags: string, memory

This is similar to:
[Is this function subject to memory fragmentation?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/22319/is-this-function-subject-to-memory-fragmentation)

I am trying to get my head around Memory fragmentation in Arduino's and embedded systems in general.

Currently I have a function in a `__lcdAux__` Class which is responsible for doing basic operation on the lcd. 
One of the members of the class is a char array `double2StrBuff1` which is used with `__dtostrf()__` to create a double which is then passed to `sprintf`. So the following function (`__lcdAux::UpdatePosition__`) is responsible for updating the position on the lcd.

```
void lcdAux::UpdatePosition(double MtXPosLengthUnits) {
    lcd->setCursor(0, 2);
    dtostrf(MtXPosLengthUnits, 0,3, double2StrBuff1);
    sprintf(lcdBuff, "X: %s", double2StrBuff1);
    lcd->print(lcdBuff);
}
```

Currently, I am under the impression that by defining once the class as a global variable and then using it throughout the program, then the char array is allocated only once memory space. Therefore by using it afterwards no memory fragmentation occurs.

However, I read that functions allocate space on the stack which is immediately recoved when the function is exited. Therefore I am curious if the following declaration is any different in terms of memory fragmentation.

```
void lcdAux::UpdatePosition(double MtXPosLengthUnits) {
    lcd->setCursor(0, 2);
    char double2StrBuff1[10];
    dtostrf(MtXPosLengthUnits, 0,3, double2StrBuff1);
    sprintf(lcdBuff, "X: %s", double2StrBuff1);
    lcd->print(lcdBuff);
}
```

To sum up:

- by putting  the declaration for variable `__char double2StrBuff1[10];__`  inside the function, is the memory allocated from the stack and therefore recovered upon exiting the function (therefore there is no need to declarate a member variable on the class level),

OR

- is the fact that `__double2StrBuff1__` is a pointer means that the pointer is allocated in the stack but the values are located in the heap (therefore what I am doing makes sense)?

PS: Because some might point out that  `__"X: %s"__` is worse in terms of memory usage and fragmentation, I'll state the following. Instead of the format string `__"X:%s"__` I use a `_PROGMEM` const `char_ array` and `__strcpy_P()_`, but to simplify the question I replaced it with the literal string , since I feel that is another problem.

Comment: The term memory fragmentation refers to heap fragmentation (when using malloc/free or new/delete). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management

Answer (score 3):

> by putting the declaration for variable char double2StrBuff1[10];
>   inside the function, is the memory allocated from the stack and
>   therefore recovered upon exiting the function

This is correct.

> is the fact that double2StrBuff1 is a pointer means that the pointer
>   is allocated in the stack but the values are located in the heap
>   (therefore what I am doing makes sense)?

No, `double2StrBuff1` is not a pointer, it's an array. In C and C++,
when you use an array identifier, it decays to a pointer in many
situations. However, for the purpose of memory allocation, an array is
*very different* from a pointer.

Heap allocation only happens when using `malloc()` and `new`.

Comment: Could you point me to some reading material which will improve my understanding of how array identifiers are different to pointers?

Comment: @NMech: Take a look at this question (and its answers, and maybe the linked references) on Stack Overflow: [What is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432).

Answer (score 2):

The examples in the question above use 1) global and 2) local aka stack allocation and do not give heap fragmentation. The heap is not involved.

Below is a version that may give heap fragmentation (though a very low risk):

```
void lcdAux::UpdatePosition(double MtXPosLengthUnits) {
    lcd->setCursor(0, 2);
    char* double2StrBuff1 = (char*) malloc(10);
    dtostrf(MtXPosLengthUnits, 0,3, double2StrBuff1);
    sprintf(lcdBuff, "X: %s", double2StrBuff1);
    lcd->print(lcdBuff);
    free(double2StrBuff1);
}
```

Please not that heap allocation is very slow compared to stack allocation.

C/C++ does not have any implicit heap allocations (in the language). A local array in a function is allocated on the stack and removed when the function returns. The only library functions that can generate stack fragmentation are [setjmp and longjmp](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__setjmp.html) if used to create a [spaghetti stack](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SpaghettiStack).